# Emacs indent-for-tab not indenting javascript in my html file

Tags: emacs

There are two issues with tabs in Emacs Live right now.

The first is that I have HTML in a script tag and the auto-indentation level is the same.

```
void setup() {
size(930, 630);
smooth();
...
```

When I hit tab it doesn't move anything anywhere unless its at the tab stop ( i believe that's the word ). It makes it to be in line with the html tag.

```
<tag>
  <script>
    if(k){
    console.log('cant indent past this');
    }
   </script>
</tag>
```

The second is that when I backspace, it moves one to the left at a time which makes me assume that spaces are being used and not tabs.

Comment: Did you check your modes? What modes are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use `mmm-mode`.

First, install `mmm-mode` from your package-manager. Run `M-x list-packages` then find `mmm-mode` and install it.

Then, open your `.emacs` or `init.el` file and add the following elisp snippet.

```
(load-library "mmm-auto")
(add-to-list 'mmm-mode-ext-classes-alist '(html-mode nil html-js))
```

Customize variable `mmm-global-mode` to `maybe` by `M-x customize-variable <RET> mmm-global-mode` and set it to `maybe`.

Restart your Emacs and open an HTML file that contains JavaScript source.